# Get broken constrains in OptaPanner with non-reversible accumulator

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to obtains list of broken constrains from a problem instance in OptaPlanner. I am using OptaPlanner version 7.0.0.Final and drools for rules engine (also 7.0.0.Final). The problem is solved correctly and without any error, but when I try to obtain broken constrains I get a NullPointer exception.

As far as I have researched, I found out, that this only happens, when I use drools accumulator without reverse operation (like max or min). Further I have made a custom accumulator, which is the exact copy from `org.drools.core.base.accumulators.LongSumAccumulateFunction` and everything works as expected, but as soon as I change the `supportsReverse()` function to return `false`, the NullPointer exception rises.

I have managed to reconstruct this problem in one of the provided examples - CloudBalancing. This is the change to `CloudBalancingHelloWorld`, it's only purpose is to obtain list of broken constraints as mentioned in this [post](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/03/13/VisualizeTheScoreAndTheConstraints.html).

```
public class CloudBalancingHelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Build the Solver
    SolverFactory<CloudBalance> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            "org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml");
    Solver<CloudBalance> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

    // Load a problem with 400 computers and 1200 processes
    CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance = new CloudBalancingGenerator().createCloudBalance(400, 1200);

    // Solve the problem
    CloudBalance solvedCloudBalance = solver.solve(unsolvedCloudBalance);

    // Display the result
    System.out.println("\nSolved cloudBalance with 400 computers and 1200 processes:\n"
            + toDisplayString(solvedCloudBalance));

    //
    //A Piece of code added - start
    //

    ScoreDirector<CloudBalance> scoreDirector = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory().buildScoreDirector();
    scoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(solvedCloudBalance);
    Collection<ConstraintMatchTotal> constrains = scoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals();
    System.out.println(constrains.size());

    //
    //A Piece of code added - end
    //



}

public static String toDisplayString(CloudBalance cloudBalance) {
    StringBuilder displayString = new StringBuilder();
    for (CloudProcess process : cloudBalance.getProcessList()) {
        CloudComputer computer = process.getComputer();
        displayString.append("  ").append(process.getLabel()).append(" -> ")
                .append(computer == null ? null : computer.getLabel()).append("\n");
    }
    return displayString.toString();
}

}
```

And this is the change to `requiredCpoPowerTotal` rule. Please note that I have done this only to demonstrate the problem. Basicaly I have changed `sum` to `max`.

```
rule "requiredCpuPowerTotal"
when
    $computer : CloudComputer($cpuPower : cpuPower)
    accumulate(
        CloudProcess(
            computer == $computer,
            $requiredCpuPower : requiredCpuPower);
        $requiredCpuPowerTotal : max($requiredCpuPower);
        (Integer) $requiredCpuPowerTotal > $cpuPower
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $cpuPower - (Integer) $requiredCpuPowerTotal);
end
```

I am really confused, because the error does not happen during planing phase, but when the `scoreDirector` recomputes the score to obtain broken constrains it does. I mean the same calculations must have happened during the planning phase right?

Anyway here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception executing consequence for rule "requiredCpuPowerTotal" in org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.handleException(DefaultAgenda.java:1256)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:438)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:379)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.fire(RuleExecutor.java:135)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:88)
at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:34)
at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:1072)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1019)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1011)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1321)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1312)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1296)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals(DroolsScoreDirector.java:134)
at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.app.CloudBalancingHelloWorld.main(CloudBalancingHelloWorld.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.core.base.accumulators.JavaAccumulatorFunctionExecutor$JavaAccumulatorFunctionContext.getAccumulatedObjects(JavaAccumulatorFunctionExecutor.java:208)
at org.drools.core.reteoo.FromNodeLeftTuple.getAccumulatedObjects(FromNodeLeftTuple.java:94)
at org.drools.core.common.AgendaItem.getObjectsDeep(AgendaItem.java:78)
at org.drools.core.reteoo.RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.getObjectsDeep(RuleTerminalNodeLeftTuple.java:359)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.extractJustificationList(AbstractScoreHolder.java:118)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder.registerConstraintMatch(AbstractScoreHolder.java:88)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(HardSoftScoreHolder.java:53)
at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.Rule_requiredCpuPowerTotal1284553313.defaultConsequence(Rule_requiredCpuPowerTotal1284553313.java:14)
at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.Rule_requiredCpuPowerTotal1284553313DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.solver.Rule_requiredCpuPowerTotal1284553313DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.innerFireActivation(RuleExecutor.java:431)
... 13 more
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Well I managed to dodge the problem by implementing my own `SumAccumulator`, that supports reverse operations by the use of `PriorityQueue`. Still wondering why the `ScoreDirector` needs reverse operations, because it already knows the assignment in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That NPE sounds like a bug in Drools. The [ConstraintMatch](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/03/13/VisualizeTheScoreAndTheConstraints.html) API should always just work. Very that you get it against the latest master version. If so, please [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER) for this with a minimal reproducer and we'll look into it.